# Difference between malloc then strcpy vs just setting it equal to the string

Tags: c

Let say I have

```
struct student
{
    char* first_name;
};

typedef struct
{
    struct student name;
} Person;

char* first_name_of_someone = "John";
```

Why do I have to malloc and then strcpy to put John in first_name? Why can't I just assign it like this

```
Person* person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
struct student s;
s.first_name = "John";
person->name = s;
```

Comment: You don't have to. It depends entirely on the expectations of the users of the `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what value to copy before hand then you don't need `malloc`

```
s.first_name = "John";
```

What if you are getting to know what value to copy during run time?
In that case you need `malloc` and `strcpy`.

```
fgets(tempbuf, sizeof tempbuf, stdin);

s.first_name = malloc(somelength);
strcpy(s.first_name, tempbuf);
```

or

```
s.first_name = tempbuf;
```

In latter case `first_name` will be always be pointing to latest value stored in `tempbuf`.

Comment: Also you should know that direct literal assignment is read-only you cannot modify its contents later stages.